# Trouble with passing by reference with linked lists in c

Tags: c, linked-list, pass-by-reference, singly-linked-list, c89

I am trying to create a new node and add it to my linked list, however inside the function I can give the data in the new node the correct value and assign it to the head of the list, but back in main, it is not keeping the value.

main:

```
insertStart(&list, &displayNum);            
displayNum = 0;         
printUI(keypad, displayNum, total);         
result = 0;
printf("Node value outside of function: %d\n",*(list.head->data));
```

Function:

```
void insertStart(LinkedList * list, int* calcData)
{
    LinkedListNode* newNode;
    newNode = (LinkedListNode*)malloc(sizeof(LinkedListNode));
    newNode->data = calcData;
    newNode->next = list->head;
    list->head = newNode;
    printf("Node value inside function: %d\n", *(list->head->data));    
}
```

So when I print the value inside the function it is correct; however, it is just 0 in the main. Can you explain what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You’re setting displayNum=0 in main, and the data field in newNode is (apparently) a pointer-to-int that is pointing to displayNum.  Perhaps you want to change the type of the LinkedListNode::data field to int instead?  Then you could set displayNum without affecting the payload of your node.

Comment: hullo, "I can give the data" --> is the data meant to be an `int *` or an `int`?

Comment: You should really show the definitions of your `LinkedList` and `LinkedListNode` structures.  And you should show how you initialize your `list` variable in the main function.  What does the `printUI()` function do?  Why does your list contain a pointer to the data rather than a copy of the data?  That invites trouble.  And on a 64-bit machine, it wastes space because you have a 64-bit pointer and a 32-bit data item that it points at, instead of just using a 32-bit data item.

Comment: Also, why are you programming to a standard that is probably older than you are, and that has not been current for about as long as you've been alive?  You should not be required to program in C89 — it is very rare that you can't use at least C99 and you should be using C11, if not not C18.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner Thanks mate, I have been trying to write this off lectures using generic linked list so they had the data as a void pointer, changing it to an int worked.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler tell that to my uni hahaha